# Configuring Babel inside vue-loader (Symfony Encore)

Tags: webpack, vue.js, symfony4, vue-loader, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony Encore for configuring a webpack for my project. So far I have enabled `vue-loader` without any problems, but I'm stuck when it comes to passing options to `vue-loader`, as the documentation is not clear enough for me, to pass or configure any options there.

I'm wondering if someone has tried to do that and if, how it's done properly.

So far I've got only the `vue-loader` enabled.

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

Encore
  // ...
  .enableVueLoader(function (options) {
    // I need to do something here to enable babel for ES5 target
  })
  .addPlugin(new VueLoaderPlugin()) // because of no support for version 15 yet
  .addEntry('vue/app', './assets/vue/app.js')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you, probably, should not use vue-loader@15.0+ as Encore [doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/311) (and therefore, you also should not add `addPlugin(new VueLoaderPlugin())` line to Encore config).

Second, you can configure Babel either by:

1. Leaving it as-is. Encore has pretty sensible defaults for Babel (which is autoconfigured if you enable vue-loader): `env` preset is used with target at `>1%` browsers coverage.
2. [Adding `.babelrc` configuration file to project folder](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/babel.html#creating-a-babelrc-file).

   ```
   {
       presets: ['env']
   }
   ```
3. [Using Babel-specific configuration callback, provided by Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/babel.html):

   ```
   .configureBabel(function(config) {
     config.presets.push('es2017');
   })
   ```
4. [By options callback for vue-plugin configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/vuejs.html) (less preferable, as it would conflict with internal configuration for Babel, performed by Encore itself. Still could be useful, if you want independent config for vue files):

   ```
   .enableVueLoader(function(options) {
     options.loaders = {
       js: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: ['env'] } }
     };
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I do appreciate the recommendations, but what would be better if we use v14 without the `addPlugin`? it seems to work just fine now.

Comment: v15 has been changed dramatically over v14. ExtractTextPlugin that is used by Encore for styles extraction doesn't work with v15 that well, thus some problems with single file components with embedded styles (afaik, i may be wrong on this). May be not important, good if it works for you =)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info.. and once again for the answer!